# Export the contour lines to vectors will only get "polygons" but not true vector "curves" in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, polygon, vector, export, contour

I am new to Google Earth Engine. Now I can successfully generate contour lines for geometry. However, when exporting these contour lines to vector curves, it just outputs vector polygons.

```
//Make the contour lines as vectors
var vectors = contourlines.reduceToVectors({
  geometry: geometry, 
  labelProperty: 'elevation',
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13
})
Map.addLayer(vectors, null, 'vectors')

//Export as KML
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: vectors,
  description: "ContourLines_to_Vector",
  folder:"Contour_Vector",
  fileFormat: "KML", //Actually it can output CSV, GEO_JSON, KML, KMZ, SHP, TF_Record_Table, but which is better?
})
```

Full code links here:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/3141daea2e8e6aea7c17eeda5732060b

Let’s see what the output KML will be shown in QGIS or Surfer:

[image]
[image]

As you may see, these “curves” are not true vector “lines”, but polygon vectors. When I dig into the KML file itself, we may see that it presents as a polygon with an outer boundary and an inner boundary, to simulate those “curves”.

[image]

From the official documents of function ee.Image.reduceToVectors (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-reducetovectors), the vector geometryType can only be set to polygon, bb, or centroid.

Is there another better way, to transfer these contour lines showing as a map layer, to truly vector lines or curves, and can be exported to KML or other files, which can be used perfectly in QGIS or Surfer?